# Creating new graph basing on cluster anylise with edges which are connectors from created group

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, igraph

```
library(network)
library(networkD3)
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
                 text = "src   target
                 cllient1  cllient2
                 cllient1  cllient4
                 cllient1  cllient6
                 cllient2  cllient3
                 cllient4  cllient1
                 cllient4  cllient3
                 cllient5  cllient6
                 cllient6  cllient5")

df_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
simpleNetwork(df,zoom = T,fontSize = 9)
```

[image]

```
wc <- cluster_walktrap(df_graph)

members <- membership(wc)

df_graph_cntrctd <- contract(df_graph, members, vertex.attr.comb = toString)

df_graph_cntrctd <-as.undirected(df_graph_cntrctd)

df_graph_cntrctd <- as_long_data_frame(df_graph_cntrctd)

idLabel <- df_graph_cntrctd[,c(2,4)]

idLabel <- idLabel[!duplicated(df_graph_cntrctd[c("to","ver2[el[, 2], ]")]),]

colnames(idLabel)[1] <- "id"
colnames(idLabel)[2] <- "title"
idLabel['label'] <- idLabel$id

FromTo <-df_graph_cntrctd[,c(1,2)]
FromTo <- FromTo[!duplicated(FromTo[c("from","to")]),]

nodes <- data.frame(id = idLabel$id, 
                    label = idLabel$label,
                    title = idLabel$title)      

edges <- data.frame(from = FromTo$from, to = FromTo$to)


network<-(visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%",height = 900 ) %>% 
            visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE))
```

[image]
So far we got a network:) And its possible to get a list of clients by whom there is a connection between groups created by walktrap. The idea is to show those clients in edges. What was created are lines of code beneath that show the list of all connections just in descending order

```
V(df_graph)$name <- members
x <- as_edgelist(df_graph, names = T)
V(df_graph)$name <- 1:vcount(df_graph)
E(df_graph)[x[,1] != x[,2]]
```

In the result we get

```
+ 1/8 edge from c92bcba (vertex names):
[1] 1->5
```

which means that group with label "1" is connected with group(label "2") by "client1" by id number 1 and "client6" by id number 5 as far as I understood.
**My question** is how to get such result like here, where we can create after all table like this:

```
  from  to  label
    1   1   NA
    1   2   Client1,Client6
    2   2   NA
```

where "from" and "to" are names of groups created from cluster analyze and Client1 and Client6 are those clients who connect that two groups

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but is very inelegant:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
             text = "src   target
             cllient1  cllient2
             cllient1  cllient4
             cllient1  cllient6
             cllient2  cllient3
             cllient4  cllient1
             cllient4  cllient3
             cllient5  cllient6
             cllient6  cllient5")

df_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
wc <- cluster_walktrap(df_graph)
df_graph0 <- df_graph
V(df_graph)$name <- membership(wc)
```

get edgelist based on membership, which translates into `from` and `to` in your request.

```
x <- as_edgelist(df_graph, names = T)
communities <- ends(df_graph, E(df_graph))
```

reset names to vertex ids (not requested but maybe usefull)

```
V(df_graph)$name <- 1:vcount(df_graph)
ids <- ends(df_graph, E(df_graph))
```

set vertex names corresponding to clients (`label`)

```
V(df_graph)$name <- V(df_graph0)$name
label <- ends(df_graph, E(df_graph))
```

store in `dataframe`

```
df_result <- data.frame(from = communities[,1], to = communities[,2],
                    label1 = label[,1], label2 = label[,2], ids1 = ids[,1], ids2 = ids[,2])
```

Which results in this:

```
  from to   label1   label2 ids1 ids2
1    1  1 cllient1 cllient2    1    2
2    1  1 cllient1 cllient4    1    3
3    1  2 cllient1 cllient6    1    5
4    1  1 cllient2 cllient3    2    6
5    1  1 cllient4 cllient1    3    1
6    1  1 cllient4 cllient3    3    6
7    2  2 cllient5 cllient6    4    5
8    2  2 cllient6 cllient5    5    4
```

Additionally you could paste `label1` and `label2` in order to get your comma separated `label` column.

EDIT: In order to "contract" labels you could do something like this:

```
 library(tidyr) 
 library(dplyr) 
 df_result$label <- paste(df_result$label1, df_result$label2, sep = ",") 
 df_nested <- df_result %>% select(from, to, label) %>% nest(-from, -to)
```

To use these nested labels as edge labels or strings paste them together:

```
 df_nested$data <- sapply(1:nrow(df_nested), 
                     function(x) paste(unlist(df_nested$data[[x]]), collapse = " "))
```

Comment: that is cool but if there are more then one connection between the groups, what to do in that case?

Comment: I am not sure if understand correctly, but I think this should work even then. Could you please provide an additional example where such a case occurs?

Comment: maybe it would be easier to give only the amount of connections, it would be also very helpful

Comment: Right. You can "contract" rows of a dataframe by using the `nest` function. I edited my answer.

Comment: `df_results$label <- paste(df_results$label1, df_results$label2, sep = ",") ` I think you wanted to write df_result, but even if to correct it gives an error after `df_nested <- df_results %>% select(from, to, label) %>% nest(-from, -to) `. like this `Error in select(., from, to, label) : unused arguments (from, to, label)`

Comment: So to be treated right `df_result$label <- paste(df_result$label1, df_result$label2, sep = ",") `
gives nice result but now if for example there were more then one connection between groups, it should add that two rows of labels, but in what we have got it will just paste another pair of clients in label beneath, we need to gather them but idk how

`

Comment: This error message could indicate that the package `dplyr` is not loaded. The gathering part then should be taken care of by the `nest` function, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Using the code of Ben Nutzer:

```
df_result$label <- paste(df_result$label1, df_result$label2, sep = ",")
```

we may find how many connections are between communities using such function:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df_result,.(from,to),nrow)
```

and get:

`from to V1
1    1  1  5
2    1  2  1
3    2  2  2`

which tells us that there is only one connection between groups